# iOS Publishing a like on object not working - Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

Using the sample code from Facebook Documentation, but its not working

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                           initWithGraphPath:@"/{object-id}/likes"
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                  id result,
                                  NSError *error) {
// Handle the result
}];
```

it gives 
*

```
error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "(#100) The parameter url is required";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
};*
```

Comment: what are the params you are sending..

Comment: its nil, let me update

Comment: so what you are trying to do... need more clarification

Comment: Using Graph Api, I need to like a custom object, for liking a custom object, document gives us this code snippet. I have given object Id, but its not working

Comment: How u have created the custom object , have you followed the procedure mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom

Comment: Yes, I have made custom object type 'toy' from here, and objects of type 'toy' from object browser. and using object-id of one of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77604/discussion-between-vizllx-and-haris).

Comment: is it the like is for  Facebook Page , as the documents states about Publishing Likes on only Facebook Pages.

Comment: Parameter can't be blank

Answer (score 0):

Facebook gives two different implementation for 'liking' custom object.

1 is here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes#publish

and other one is here.
https://developers:facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes#create

Its the code in second link which actually works

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
  @"object": @"http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791",
};
/* make the API call */
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/me/og.likes"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

Comment: That is what I have mentioned "is it the like is for Facebook Page , as the documents states about Publishing Likes on only Facebook Pages." but  later I can see you are liking an external post, which obviously need og.likes API. Good to see , you found it finally.